# Ruby - 'require': 127: The specified procedure could not be found (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

So, I have a small Ruby program, which is a simple "Hello World" - the code is below

```
require 'ray'

Ray.game 'Hello world!', :size => [800, 600] do
  register { add_hook :quit, method(:exit!) }
scene :hello do
  @text = text 'Hello, Ruby!', :angle => 30, :at => [100, 100], :size => 30
  render { |win| win.draw @text }
end
scenes << :hello
end
```

and it worked just fine on my Win7-32 bit machine. However, when I took the exact same program to my Win7-64 bit machine, the Ruby interpreter spitted out the following message:

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 127:
The specified procedure could not be found.   - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
/gems/ray-0.2.0/lib/ray_ext.so (LoadError)
```

From the error message, it seemed like the "ray_ext.so" was missing, but actually it was there:

[image]

Both PCs have the exact same version of Ruby (1.9.3), and exact same list of gems installed, yet how come the exact same program worked just fine on the 32-bit Win7 but failed on the 64-bit Win7?

I tried to re-install the gem (ray) again, as well as updating the gem list, but that didn't resolve the issue. From what I discovered from the web, it seemed that this was a "dll" linkage problem (correct me if I'm wrong), but I didn't know how to fix it (excuse me, I'm still a noob in Ruby), except to re-install the gem - which didn't work.

Is there anything else that I can try? Do you think that this is purely the gem's problem (which is not compatible with Win7-64 bit)?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just installed `ray` gem on Windows-7 64bit. It works.

Comment: What Ruby version are you using? Mine said ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06) [i386-mingw32]. It must have something to do with the path linkage, but I just couldn't figure out how to get around it.

Comment: In addition, if I tried to run one of the apps from the samples folder, I got the exact same error message as above - except that now it complained "ray_ext.so" not found in "...\ray-0.2.0\ext" folder (not in "lib" folder as shown above). Of course, the .so file was presented in both locations when I checked, but somehow the interpreter couldn't "see" it. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

In short, use [latest Ruby](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=167).

When I install Jekyll on my Windows 7 64bit, I got the same error (Yes, the version of Ruby is 1.9.3）. It didn't disappear until I change my Ruby to 2.0.0 (not 2.0.0-x64).

Although I don't understand Ruby at all, I hope this can solve your problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem.  I tried setting the right oracle bin path pointing to oci.dll, that didn't work.  I copied over the oci.dll to ruby\bin directory and later it gave me another error.  I had to copy orauts.dll and there you go...the application worked.

Hope that helps others.